# How do I stop commas from breaking my float conversions in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

I have a simple Cocoa app with a Table View. Each cell of the table represents a floating point value. The floats are stored in an object with 5 float properties, the names of which match the identifiers I have set for the columns in my table view.

I have managed to connect it all up so that the stored floating point values are editable, and it all works great apart from when the number in question happens to be 1,000 or more. In this case, after entering the number, it comes back to the table view formatted with a comma.

So far so good, except if you enter a number with a comma in it, everything after the comma is lost in the float conversion.

So, for example:

- 45.0 becomes 45
- 999.9 becomes 999.9
- 0 becomes 0.0 (not sure why the decimal point displays for zero)
- 1000 becomes 1,000
- 1,000 becomes 1
- 2,312 becomes 2

So the problem is with the last three examples. Commas are automatically inserted for numbers 1000 or greater, but commas are not interpreted correctly if they are entered.

I'm not explicitly doing the float conversion in my code, it is being handled behind the scenes when I call setValueForKey on the property and the string conversion is happening when I call valueForKey - ids are being passed around in my code.

Here is the relevant code in my data controller:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    TCPointGroup *pg = [points objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *ident = [tableColumn identifier];
    return [pg valueForKey:ident];
}

- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    TCPointGroup *pg = [points objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *ident = [tableColumn identifier];
    [pg setValue:object forKey:ident];
}
```

And here is the definition of the object which holds the floating point values:

```
@interface TCPointGroup : NSObject {

}

@property float pt_Xw;
@property float pt_Yw;
@property float pt_Zw;
@property float pt_xd;
@property float pt_yd;

+ (id)newWithArray:(NSArray*)array;
- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray*)array;

@end
```

It seems weird to me that commas are inserted by the float to string conversion, but not understood correctly by the string to float conversion that is taking place.

Any suggestions on how to make it work in an expected way?

Comment: Are you sure that the TCPointGroup class isn't adding the commas? I don't think Cocoa would do that automatically.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Whatever automatic float to string conversion is happening is inserting commas.

Answer (score 2):

It seems I have found a solution. The NSNumberFormatter class is able to understand string versions of a floating point number with commas. The solution is to instantiate an NSNumberFormatter, set its format to decimal style and call numberFromString. This NSNumber object can then be sent to the object expecting a float.

Updated code for the relevant method below...

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSNumber* value = [_formatter numberFromString:object];
    if( value ) {
        TCPointGroup *pg = [points objectAtIndex:row];
        NSString *ident = [tableColumn identifier];
        [pg setValue:value forKey:ident];
    }
}
```

The _formatter object is created during the init phase of the data handling class, like so:

```
    _formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [_formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
```

**Edit** Thanks to @yinkou for the comment below which led to creating only one formatter instead of creating and destroying one per call.

Comment: Yeah, but don't do it that way. Make the number formatter static or store it in a property (or ivar) since instantiating the same number formatter over and over again can result in a high performance loss.

Comment: Avoid premature optimization. If we're instantiating a handful of formatters, it's fast enough. If we need thousands per second, caching the formatters is a big win.

Comment: You really don't need more than one… unless you're formatting things differently per cell?

Comment: Thanks @yinkou I agree, reinstantiating it 50 times whenever the table refreshes is totally unnecessary and very easy to fix. Moving the number formatter to a member variable of my data handler.